# Persistant phantom volume mount points, how to prevent?

Tags: macos, backup, mount, reboot, disk-volume

Every time I reboot my Mac a mount point for a drive I don't even have connected is recreated in my /Volumes/ dir.  I can delete it, but next time I reboot it comes back.  How can I find out what is creating this?

P.S.  At one time I did have CCC along with some other backup utilities installed on this system, that were setup to backup a volume of that name, but they have been removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you removed Carbon Copy Cloner by dragging it to the trash, I'm guessing there may be remnants of CCC still on your system.

Check these locations and delete them these if they exist:

```
/Library/Application Support/com.bombich.ccc
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.bombich.ccchelper.plist
/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.bombich.ccchelper
/Users/yourname/Library/Application Support/com.bombich.ccc
```

Comment: I just checked and none of those files existed (I would have ran an included CCC uninstalled if the dmg had one), also did 'sudo find / -name 'com.bombich*' and no results either.

Comment: There is an "Uninstall CCC" command within the app itself. Maybe re-install CCC and peform the uninstall as they intend?

Comment: Looks like there was a hidden Uninstall option in the File menu (have to hold down Option while the menu is open to access it), I'll reboot the system when I get home and check if that was it, although it could always be something else; the reason I mentioned CCC in the question was because I had found mention of some people having similar issues related to it.